# Is it worth doing a 'Pipe Leak Detection' PhD (industrywise)?

Tags: phd, united-kingdom

I have been offered a PhD opportunity in a UK university and the topic is 'Pipe Leak Detection (using acoustic waves)'.

My question is, is it worth doing a PhD in this area considering the industrial opportunities available for such area of expertise?

** the research is co-funded by the UK Water Industry Research (UKWIR), but I am not sure (at the moment) about the possibility of joining them after the PhD.

Could someone with relevent expertise or someone working in the field advice me or drop some comments. I really appreciate it, thanks in advance for all.

Comment: One hint: think about other applications of the work. If you know a lot about how waves move in fluids, for example, then you can also look for interesting research jobs in sonar and oceanography, among other fields. That's a big hammer that can hit many nails. But if you are just a glorified technician on leaky pipes, then you're really taking a big gamble that you'll be able to get a whole career working on exactly that same problem. In other words, a very specialized hammer that can only hit one nail. Sometimes this is an OK gamble, but other times no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it sounds awesome.  Huge connection to industry, society.  Both directly with the method and then tangentially with pipes in general (water, oil, gas, sewage).  The basic things you do in acoustics, mechanics, fluid flow will be good training also.

And then the integrative learnings from putting a "fancy" technique onto a basic problem.  And this is whether it "works" or not (in terms of physical results or economic feasibility).  For you, it's all upside in the learning and the connections.

Jump on that thing.  Like yesterday!

Comment: Reads a lot like snark. Should it be flagged?

Comment: I actually mean it.  I know that sounds crazy to a pure academic.  But getting involved with something contrarian can be HUGE upside.  Instead of doing string theory, do something on Raman spectroscopy of fouled catalysts in a refinery.  you will still use/learn all kinds of physics.  And get both direct and indirect connections to industry, other scientific topics.  The scary thing...I'm not sarcastic.  I actually LIKE applied stuff, not just try to lie about it to get grants!

Comment: There's probably even learnings applicable to systems we're not even thinking of (medicine, blood vessels, refineries, etc.).  Think of how "grubby" time domain reflectometry sounds but how much application it has had, both directly and tangentially.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometry  And connections to deeper topics like spectral analysis.

Comment: OTOH, an extremely esoteric field can lead quite quickly to a professional dead end. Studying esoterica in the odd moments is a bit safer.

Comment: If you have a curious streak, you can find connections.  Maybe if you're a weaker student, it ends up being a dead end.  Because you lack the ability to extend the practical to the theoretical or move from physics to engineering. I am probably unconsciously biased because I think of people who can make those jumps...versus just moving down the straight path of number theory or whatever.  Actually...screw it...even for a weak student, there is benefit to being in this sort of applied area (the direct industry connect).  I MEAN IT when I say JUMP ON IT.

Comment: thanks all for your comments and really appreciate all the efforts, I am leaned towards YES now :), but sadly now the question is ON-HOLD :(